# What internal algorithm does C# use to generate random number using Next method of Random class instance?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

C# has provided an inbuilt functionality to generat random numbers using Next method of Random class instance. I want to understand the algorithm C# internally uses to generate random number. And does every number has equal probability of being generated by this method?

Comment: It depends which runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The source for the `Random` class in .Net 4.8 is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs)

In .Net Core, it's [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Random.cs)